# How to prevent a hasMany relation from loading in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

Let's say I have the following model:

Machine.php (simplified):

```
class Machine
{
    public function organization()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Organization::class);
    }
    public function readings()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Reading::class);
    }
}
```

I want to write a query to get the data of all the machines, but not the `hasMany` relation.

Currently, if I write the following in a controller: `return Machine::where('organization_id', Auth::user()->organization_id)->get();`, the resulting array will look like this:

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "organization_id": 1,
        "readings": []
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "organization_id": 1,
        "readings": []
    }
]
```

How can I remove the `readings` arrays from this output? I don't only want to manipulate the JSON, since getting this data from the database also takes a considerable amount of time.

---

EDIT: So unfortunately I managed to removed the culprit in my MCVE, which was a defined attribute on the Machine class, which queried the `readings` field in every case. Removing that attribute solved my problem. (See the comments under this question.)

Comment: Do you have any accessor and appends within the Machine model?

Comment: @MateusJunges Yes, I have the following: `protected $appends = ['removable'];`, and it's defined as `return $this->readings->isEmpty();`. ...and now I realize that this also needs to be hidden, otherwise the query runs anyway.

Comment: Yes, you are using the `readings` to set the `removable` attribute, so you need to find another way to do this or you can not remove the `readings` relation, just hide from json.

Comment: @MateusJunges That makes sense, thanks for your help!

Comment: Glad that i can help you :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

laravel actually mention this thing on their docs [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-serialization#hiding-attributes-from-json)

you can simply add this on your model

```
protected $hidden = ['readings'];
```

in case you needed to use it somewhere, then you can use makeHidden method like this

```
Machines::somequery()->get()->makeHidden(['readings'])->toArray();
```

Comment: Thanks, this indeed hides the array from the resulting JSON. Do you know whether this still runs the SQL query to get all the readings from the database though? (I couldn't find that information in the docs, and I'm not sure how to check.)

Comment: since `makeHidden` is method used on collection, it still querying the database to get the `readings` relation

Comment: @martonbognar unless you do something like Machines::with('readings'), it won't queries

Answer (score 0):

you can use

```
protected $hidden = ['readings'];
```

put in the first place you need to create an api resource or transformer
check this link
https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-resources